# GetContentPane and SetContentPane Eror

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, contentpane

```
package javagraphics;
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import static java.lang.Math.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class JavaGraphics extends JFrame{  




class DrawArea extends JFrame
{   

   Point A,B,C,D,E,F = null;     
   int Loop =25; 
   int length = 100; 
    public DrawArea()
    {    
    //x=1366,y=705
     A = new Point (200,200);

    }

   @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

         }

    for (int i = 0; i <500; i++) {

    **some code to draw a line**
        }

     }

}
 public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
    JavaGraphics canvas = new JavaGraphics();
    canvas.setSize(1366,768); 
    canvas.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    canvas.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);    
    canvas.setContentPane(new DrawArea());
    canvas.pack();
    canvas.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

My question is about setcontentpane and getcontentpane
in the last bar "canvas.setContentPane(new DrawArea());" , my set contentpane was error 
can u find the answer please , and tell me why is that error like that?
Thank u..

"canvas.setContentPane(new DrawArea());"
when its running my window just gray not showing the line pattern that i have been code its said "non-static variable this cannot be refrenced from a static context"

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: "canvas.setContentPane(new DrawArea());"
when its running my window just gray not showing the line pattern that i have been code @JCx

Comment: What is the error message though?